# C—Bus error with memory locations

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I'm trying to display the contents of a specific memory location, and I'm getting a puzzling error. Below is the function I'm using:

```
int mem_display(Cmd *cp, char *arguments)
{
    int x = 10;
    char c = 'c';
    int input = 0;
    sscanf(arguments, " %x", &input)
    int *location = (int*)input;

    printf("location of int x: %p\n", (void*)&x);
    printf("location of char c: %p\n", (void*)&c);
    printf("%x\n", *location);
    return 0;
}
```

When I type the proper command (md) followed by the location of x (ffbef54c), it displays correctly. However, when I try one more or one less, I get an error:

```
UNIX-tutor> md ffbef54c
location of int x: ffbef54c
location of char c: ffbef54b
ffbef54c
a
UNIX-tutor> md ffbef54b
location of int x: ffbef54c
location of char c: ffbef54b
ffbef54b
Bus error (core dumped)
```

Is there a problem with trying to display a char as an int? I need to be able to display the hex value of whatever is stored in the location I enter. Any assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system requires correct alignment to dereference pointers. Make sure you input a value with the correct alignment (likely `sizeof(int)` in your case). Alternatively, just use a `char` pointer instead. You should be able to access any address that way - just make sure it's one your program has mapped and is allowed to access!

Comment: Is there any way I can know if a value has correct alignment or not besides testing to see if I get a bus error?

Comment: Sure you can test the value; make sure it's got the right number of low order bits set to zero.

Comment: A lot of this terminology is new to me, so unfortunately I don't know precisely what that means. I need to be able to display 16 bits in a row from any location the program has access to, so is there a way I can display the value at location ffbef54b, or is it completely off limits?

Comment: Use a `char` pointer (twice, probably, in the case of the 16-bit value), or align the pointer, extract a larger type and then mask/shift to get the byte or bytes you want.

Comment: Will using a char pointer be universal? If I switch over, I don't get any more bus errors, but the value at ffbef54c now displays as "0." ffbef54b, however, looks correct. It's "63."

Comment: Yes, a `char` pointer is safe, but you'll need to read multiple times to get the whole `int` if it's larger than a `char`.